# Constants in Laravel 5.7 throw already defined error

Tags: php, caching, constants, laravel-5.7

I have created a project in Laravel 5.7 and created the file constants.php in config directory. When I tried to run php artisan config:cache, I am getting the following error.
"ErrorException  : Constant XXX_XXX already defined"

I have defined all the constants as define('XXXX_XXXX', 'bla bla'); All these are standard constants needed for my package.

I have done the following:

1. I have searched the whole project and it is clear that I have never defined the same anywhere else.
2. If I remove that constant, it shows error at the next define().
3. If I remove the file from config directory, the artisan command gets executed successfully and I can see the config cache file in bootstrap/cache directory. but my program aborts due to error (as constants are not defined) even after I paste back the file in config directory.
4. If I remove the config cache file from the bootstrap/cache directory, the code gets executed perfectly normal ( i have not ran the command config:cache).

I very much need this constants and the same time cache the configs to run. I am not able guess the problem.

Note : Contents of `config/contants.php` all are define('XXX', 'xxx'); Simply echo XYZ; wherever needed. Standard php constants.

Comment: Add check `if (!defined('XXXX_XXXX')) {  // define constant }`

Comment: what's the content of the `config/constants.php` ? and how do you access them ?

Answer (score 2):

try this way

define constant value below

```
if (!defined('constant')) define('constant', 'value');
```

Comment: i have replaced the first constant with the above mentioned code. The php artisan config:cache shows the same error.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. I have done that. I believe, the php artisan config:cache command clears and rebuilds it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether it is correct but the way it worked is as follows:

1. I moved the constants.php from App/config/ to App/ (along with other models)
2. I modified the composer.json in the "autoload" with

   "files": [
       "app/constants.php"
   ]
3. I ran composer dump-autoload
4. Then I ran the php artisan config:cache

It had build the new config file in bootstrap and the code is executing normal.

Answer (score 0):

i have a great solution for this. please follow this step :

1 -> add new file `constantHelper.php` inside directory `app/Helpers`

2 -> edit file `composer.json` and set auto load files

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "app/Helpers/constantHelper.php"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "files": [
      "app/Helpers/constantHelper.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

this is my complete code inside `composer.json`

```
{
  "name": "nurzazin/lumen",
  "description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "laravel",
    "lumen"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": "7.3.*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
    "wn/lumen-generators": "^1.3"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "app/Helpers/constantHelper.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
      "database/seeds",
      "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "files": [
      "app/Helpers/constantHelper.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
      "tests/"
    ]
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

3 -> run command `composer install` or `composer dump-autoload`